# Ember-i18n Missing translation: it is not working with Ember Twiddle Example

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

i don't know why, but can't get the addon Ember-i18n working, what do i false?

you can see my Ember Twiddle under https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/736ba26820e429cd683a5eb54416996b?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is ok but one point. The fallback language is `en` and you didn't define the default. Also you didn't define anywhere that the default lang is `de`.

Please do below in application route :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   i18n: Ember.inject.service(),

  beforeModel(){
    this.set('i18n.locale', 'de');
  }
});
```